# Not receiving Fragment in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website like this:
https://example.com/path1/path2/#!portal/1

I've inserted the script of ga and I've made the next modification in the code to receive the fragment (after hash #):

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'page': location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash
      });
```

But when I check the ga page, in "Behavior/Behavior Flow/Site Content/All Pages" I only have:
https://example.com/path1/path2/

I'm new in ga, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you checking in real-time as well to see if it is showing that way, without the hash?

Comment: @nyuen In real-time show the same url without the hash too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have in your question will work just fine. I think there may have been a temporary glitch affecting hash URLs, but everything seems to be working now, so I'd just try it again.

Also, since it sounds like you're building an AJAX site, I'd recommend taking a look at the developer guide on tracking single page applications with Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - overriding the page value didn't do anything, despite the fact that this is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).

I finally replaced the hash with another character (two actually I used a double slash //) in the tracking code and used a search-replace filter in the view settings to restore the hash character.

If anybody has a proper solution I'll take it in a jiffy, but this is at least a workaround that does the job.

Comment: Well thank you, this will help me until I find THE way

Comment: I'd avoid doing things like this in the future. All software will have bugs, but as long as you're implementing what's recommended in the documentation, when those bugs are fixed your code will work. When you try workarounds like this, there's no guarantee it will work in the future.

Comment: @PhilipWalton, in general I totally agree. But even the previous GA versions did not process hashes and so I've been using this particular workaround for the last four years or so (besides there's not really much that could happen).